# deleting logs in uplink

Tags: uplink

Is going to the console and then "cd log" followed by "delete", different from using the log deleter on each entry?

Comment: BTW if you like uplink, check out the sorta remake of it http://www.exosyphen.com/page_hacker-evolution.html, people do seem to like uplink better (I do) but it's not a bad game.

Comment: cool.. will check it out, the screenshots are amazing :)

Comment: i checked out the demo, it is super awesome! thanks for suggesting it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not different, but in both cases there is a problem.

There will be logs for connection and disconnection which are generated by users (including you), and doing a `delete` in `log` will cause the log entries for your current connection to be deleted (i.e. the connection entry and the authentication entry), however, when you disconnect, another log entry documents your disconnection.

If an administrator just sees a disconnection log, they can trace that connection (almost?) as easily as if you hadn't deleted the connection and authentication entries.

It's important that there are matching entries for connections and disconnections, therefore, you should not delete **all** the logs in the folder, just make sure that there will only be sets of log entries available (i.e. connection and disconnection — I tend to remove even the current authentication log entry). I'm not certain if the game knows whether two log entries actually belong to the same connection, or if it 'assumes' that you were connected the whole time.

Comment: interesting point. this is a wily game. But what i wanted to know was that is `delete` in console effectively using the log-deleter that I have. Say, i don't have a log-deleter can I still use this? or if I have a v2.0 would it be different as compared to v1.0?

Comment: That's an interesting question. I would speculate that `delete` does not use your log deleter — it should still work even if you don't have one.

Comment: alright, i will test this theory and post back :)

Comment: Note that log deleter v4 is *significantly* better than the v1 because it moves all the other logs up to cover that there was ever anything in that log slot.

Answer (score 4):

I just checked, `delete log` is the same as using `log deleter v1`. It can be done even if you don't have a `log deleter` and is independent of the `log deleter` version you might have. I will leave @Alan's answer as accepted :)

Comment: Did you check it's still v1 when you own a v4 one? I.e. can logs deleted via the console still be undeleted?

Answer (score 1):

If you delete an log file, a server admin just might notice. If you delete an entry within a log file, it's a lot harder to detect the change. Also IIRC later you get a better log entry deleter which also renumbers the logs, i.e moves the later ones back up in sequence so they aren't noticed to be missing.

Answer (score 0):

First to address above:

log > delete only uses v1, however because its considered accessed from an internal console remotely that is why you don't actually need log delete to do it, however I recommend against it, you need log_deleter and preferably v4.

I wish I could find a way to copy logs, create logs and use v4 on console but in the meantime there are useful methods for watching your tracks.

Do always keep your last connection establish log because of the disconnect created on the last access, or disconnect, reconnect, delete the previous log, but then you are in an endless cycle.  with that in mind, clean everything but your last connection log,

(Break) you must understand my bounce. InterNic, Uplink test, uplink internal, uplink all others, all databases, all banks, All Internal access machines, all public access.   later I plan to add mainframes and file servers and LAN's, after internal access

Back to the tracks, I then load my route which ends at the last public access and connect to InterNic, clean all routes (ESPECIALLY FROM 127.000.0.1 (The gateway), leave only the last pair of connection/disconnect log and the newly mad connection established.  Then I goto the uplink test, though being traced never and issue, do the same thing cleaning all Routes including gateway, InterInc, and the leaving only 3 lines at the top, connection established, closed, established.

If you have v4, a trinity gateway, 8 CPUs at 200, 8 or higher modem, feel free to only leave just the very last established connection on both places.  Always clear admins and routes on both locations... Will never get caught.

I even had a motion sensor that was going of and I nuked my gateway, only for me to get an email saying it was for a crime I never committed... oh always keep plenty of funds to buy everything back... and that is why file copy and delete are sold in the software store which many always wondered, blow the gateway its like starting from less than scratch. Lesson learned for me, don't nuke the gateway when you overkill on covering your tracks.

For those who prefer the console, and don't get me wrong its quicker and I like it too, here is the best trick... Keep log_undeleter...

Keep in mind a company or another hacker may have this helpful item too, but here is how this works.

console: do log>delete, watch and count how many lines down was the last connection establish, this will depend on what all you did prior to accessing console...  usually between 1-5 lines down unless its a tougher mission, when the delete finished, leave console, goto logs, and Undeleted the for example the 3rd line down, BAM connection established log is undeleted, so when you disconnect there is a normal connect/disconnect consistency.

Its still leaves log traces, that can be undeleted too, but it does work.  you still need to clear your gateway routes from Internic, and again I like to clear my routes from internic to test server as well... I also tend to after a bigger more risky mission overkill and go admin on uplink internal access (DO NOT TRY UNLESS YOU HAVE A SUPER COMPUTER LIKE DESCRIBED ABOVE.)

Delete all user and admin access, routes, and all connections but the most recent single one, this could take time if you don't upkeep this every once in awhile.

Sometimes I will even clear a few logs of some of the internals just for upkeep, unnecessary but its kinda fun.